# Invisible cancel button on MFMailComposeViewController in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my application, I use this code to make all navigation bar components white:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor = .white
```

The problem when I use MFMailComposeViewController is the cancel button is not visible because the navigation bar is white too:

[image: Missing cancel button]

I tried to change tintColor, but it doesn't work:

```
myMailPicker.navigationBar.tintColor = .myColor
```

Do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?